# mysql query : null values behavior when left joining

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

The question might be very simple, but I don't understand how the null values behave in an mysql syntax. Suppose I have this prepared request :

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 
   on t1.id = t2.id 
   and some_entry = :value 
where t2.the_id is null
```

some_entry is a table2 entry, t2.the_id is the incremental index of table2. What will be the output if table2 is empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
What will be the output if table2 is empty?
```

Even if `table2` is empty, it will still display all records on `table1` because you have used `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: even if some_entry is a table2 column ?

Comment: yes.  try this `and some_entry = :value 
where t2.the_id is NOT null` to see the difference.

Comment: btw, what is the reason of this request, because if table2 is not empty, t2.the_id will not be null ??

Comment: Not at all times. These are the times when `t2.the_id` will be null: **1.)** when `the_id` has no value at all **2.)** when `t1.id = t2.id` but the value of `b.some_entry <> :value`. **3.)** when `t1.id <> t2.id`

Comment: It's the inverse of select t1.* 
from table1 t1 
 join table2 t2 
   on t1.id = t2.id 
   and some_entry = :value